# How can I implement fixed socket count on proxy->server connection?

Tags: proxy, netty

I read netty proxy example, (https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy )
and I have two requirement.

1. I want to use fixed-count connection on proxy->server.
   On proxy example, proxy->server conn. count equals client->proxy conn. count.
   It may be too many.
2. When client->proxy connection ends, proxy->server connection has to be keep alived
   And when new client->proxy connection established, reuse proxy->server connections.

How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

The first requirement can be realized rather easily by using a [DefaultChannelGroup](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) to store your channels. Assuming that the `ChannelHandler` which is accepting incoming connections is a `singleton`, then you can use the following code.

```
    // initialize channelgroup in your singleton handler
ChannelGroup ALL_CONNECTIONS = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

...
@Override    
public synchronized void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception 
{        
    if(ALL_CONNECTIONS.size() > 100){
        ctx.channel().close();// dont accept further connections
    }else{
        ALL_CONNECTIONS.add(ctx.channel());
        // do whatever logic.
    }
}
```

I think you are thinking of "connection pooling" for the second requirement. If so, its not a great idea I think. Since, when a new client "connects" to your server, it is always a new connection since it is coming from outside of your network. However I am not sure of this and someone with more knowledge can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both what your need, i think, is a client with connection pool.

Both HttpComponents and AsyncHttpClient support pooling, You could have a look at the codes in AsyncHttpClient which also have a netty based implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I said TCP proxy, not HTTP.